# Floodlight in Eclipse

Tags: java, generics

I'm following [a guide](http://docs.projectfloodlight.org/display/floodlightcontroller/How+to+Write+a+Module) trying to manage the floodlight controller through eclipse.

Everything seems to work fine until I try to define the Packets_in messages with this code:

```
@Override
public net.floodlightcontroller.core.IListener.Command receive(IOFSwitch sw, OFMessage msg, FloodlightContext cntx) {
    Ethernet eth =
            IFloodlightProviderService.bcStore.get(cntx,
                                        IFloodlightProviderService.CONTEXT_PI_PAYLOAD);

    Long sourceMACHash = Ethernet.toLong(eth.getSourceMACAddress());
    if (!macAddresses.contains(sourceMACHash)) {
        macAddresses.add(sourceMACHash);
        logger.info("MAC Address: {} seen on switch: {}",
                HexString.toHexString(sourceMACHash),
                sw.getId());
    }
    return Command.CONTINUE;
```

I get a error at the ".add" line telling me:

> `The method add(capture#3-of?) in the type Set<capture3#-of?> is not applicable for the arguments(long)`

Why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: The documentation says you should declare the set as `protected Set macAddresses;`. Based on the error message, you have changed this to `protected Set<?> macAddresses;`. You should change it to `protected Set<Long> macAddresses;`, then it should work. Otherwise, maybe provide a bit more code.